# Is it possible or how to further DRY this XML statement?

Tags: xml, xslt, dry

From other people experience, it seems that it is case by case, their question is usually how to dry this or how to dry that... So in my case, it is something similar, instead for a special case, I try to ask more generally:

say, I have an xml code with the following lines

`<input type="text" defaultValue="" name="Fax_Label" label="Fax Label" />`

which will be parsed and then using XSLT to stylize later.

Because I am coming from more like CSS, PHP, JS, based on my php experience
I can create an array and a loop like this to accomplish so I can separate the parameters with template block eg.

```
$para_arr = array(
   // type | name | label
   array('text', 'Fax_Text', 'Fax Text')
);

for( $i=0; $i<count($para_arr); $i++){
echo '<input type="{$para_arr[i][0]}" defaultValue="" name="{$para_arr[i][1]}" label="{$para_arr[i][2]}" />';
}
```

is there any XML equivalent way to accomplish the same things?
Many thanks.

The above will be part of the history to this question and let other people why I am being downvoted.
Old Question: How to DRY the XML/XSLT like PHP doing it with array and for-loop?

Revised questions here:
Is it possible to DRY this structure?
Because there will be over 30 fields, it is quite tedious and hard to maintenance to copy and paste all of them and edit them one by one.

```
<namespace>
    <cms_data>
        <inputGRP>
            <input type="text" defaultValue="" name="nickname_label" label="NickName Label" />
            <input type="text" defaultValue="" name="nickname_error" label="NickName Error" />
            <input type="text" defaultValue="" name="rowTitle_login" label="Row Heading Login" />
            <input type="text" defaultValue="" name="title_label" label="Title Label" />
            <input type="text" defaultValue="" name="title_error" label="Title Error" />
        </inputGRP>
    </cms_data>
</namespace>
```

Comment: It is difficult to give a specific answer because the question is not specific enough. In general, XSLT works with XML after it has been parsed - so this work has already been done for you.

Comment: You generate an XML (using DOM for example). Xslt reads values from a DOM and transforms it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried to change the question more specifically. Maybe I should put some more snippets that I intended to achieve for.

Comment: I still have no idea what your question is. XSLT is not PHP. Ask not how to use PHP tools in XSLT; ask how to accomplish a task in XSLT.

Comment: I see your point, um, it might be due to my thinking is based on my mother language(not English obviously) so I want to express something like "how to accomplish this task by analogizing with another programming language I know", I will refine the question and content soon after the current work. Much thanks for your time.

Comment: I suspect you will find that XSLT, being largely a *declarative* language, has few analogies with an *imperative* language such as PHP.

Comment: I have revised the question and be more specified to my question. Many thanks for every veterans.

Comment: I am afraid the question isn't any clearer now. XSLT is a **transformation** tool: it transforms input XML in a given format to another XML (or HTML or text) format. If you have a question about that, then post your input and your expected output. Otherwise this is not going anywhere.

Comment: I mean it is possible to put the name, label and type separately from the structure of the current tag so that the whole structure can be generated and maintenance easily?

Answer (score 0):

I read your question as "knowing how to drop PHP variables into HTML echo, how is this done in XSLT code e.g. inside a loop".
To output XML data in XSLT one uses  where data is the xpath to the actual data inside your XML file or a XSLT variable. This doesn't work inside an HTML attribute because angle brackets are not allowed there. Instead you can use attribute value templates (AVT, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates), writted as {data} just like your PHP example only using xpath (or xslt variable).
Don't shoot me if I missed the point, I'm not native english speaking.

Comment: Your comment is great, I change the title more specificially

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if this is what you are asking, but XSLT does not itself have a concept of arrays. However, you could define some XML like so

```
<array>
    <array>
        <value>text</value>
        <value>Fax_Label</value>
        <value>Fax Label</value>
    </array>
</array>
```

Then, for your 'loop' you would employ a template-based approach, so select the 'array' elements

```
    <xsl:variable name="para_arr" select="/array" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$para_arr/array" />
```

Then template itself would look this this

```
<xsl:template match="array">
    <input type="{value[1]}" defaultValue="" name="{value[2]}" label="{value[3]}" />
</xsl:template>
```

Note the use of Attribute Value Templates here to output the values. The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally. Also note in XSLT that indexes start at 1, not 0.

Better still if you defined your XML something like this

```
<array>
    <array>
        <value name="type">text</value>
        <value name="name">Fax_Label</value>
        <value name="label">Fax Label</value>
    </array>
</array>
```

Then your XSLT could be amended to cope with an unlimited number of attributes too

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="para_arr" select="/array" />

        <xsl:apply-templates select="$para_arr/array" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="array">
        <input defaultvalue="">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="value" />
        </input>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="value">
        <xsl:attribute name="{@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the XML above could be placed in a separate file to the main XML you are transforming, in which case just use the `document` function to access it:

```
<xsl:variable name="para_arr" select="document('myArray.xml')/array" />
```

Comment: I will try and because I am being thrown this area of programming. I will setup iis from scratch, understanding the whole area of development through from .Net, C#, XML and XSLT processing. I will surely check this back, try and feedback. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @simongcc So, did you perhaps forget to "check back"? Is Tim's code the solution? If so, please accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The closest structure to an array that XSLT has is a sequence. A sequence of atomic values, like strings, is basic so you would need to come up with your own scheme to reproduce something like a multidimensional array.

Here's an example where I have 2 sequences. The first sequence is the attribute names. The second sequence is the values.

The second sequence also needs to specify which `entry` it belongs in. To handle this I added the prefix `e#:` to each value. For example, the entries for the first `entry` have the prefix `e1:`. I can then use those values to group everything together.

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="names" select="('type','defaultValue','name','label')"/>
    <xsl:param name="values" select="('e1:text','e1:','e1:nickname_label','e1:NickName Label',
                                      'e2:text','e2:','e2:nickname_error','e2:NickName Error',
                                      'e3:text','e3:','e3:rowTitle_login','e3:Row Heading Login',
                                      'e4:text','e4:','e4:title_label','e4:Title Label',
                                      'e5:text','e5:','e5:title_error','e5:Title Error'
                                      )"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <namespace>
            <cms_data>
                <inputGRP>            
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="$values" group-by="tokenize(.,':')[1]">
                        <input>
                            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                                <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                                <xsl:attribute name="{$names[$pos]}" select="tokenize(.,':')[2]"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </input>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </inputGRP>
            </cms_data>
        </namespace>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output** (Using any well-formed/valid XML input. I used the stylesheet itself for input.)

```
<namespace>
   <cms_data>
      <inputGRP>
         <input type="text"
                defaultValue=""
                name="nickname_label"
                label="NickName Label"/>
         <input type="text"
                defaultValue=""
                name="nickname_error"
                label="NickName Error"/>
         <input type="text"
                defaultValue=""
                name="rowTitle_login"
                label="Row Heading Login"/>
         <input type="text"
                defaultValue=""
                name="title_label"
                label="Title Label"/>
         <input type="text"
                defaultValue=""
                name="title_error"
                label="Title Error"/>
      </inputGRP>
   </cms_data>
</namespace>
```

I'm not sure if this is any more maintainable than what you are currently doing. One advantage is that by using the `xsl:param` you can pass in the sequences at runtime. This would allow you to maintain or generate the names and values separate from the XSLT.